# VBa shows the wrong value

Tags: vba, excel

I asked this question on reddit, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to try it here as well: Here is [the link](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/8ayadz/vba_shows_wrong_value/). I will just copy and paste what I wrote there.

Hi,

so for work I have about 90 Excel from which I need to pull data every week. I'm pretty new, but I thought I would write a VBA for it, since I don't want to spend 3 days a week just doin that.
However apparently I messed it up.

This is what my code looks like.

```
Sub Makro1()
Dim oWB1210 As Workbook: Set oWB1210 = Application.Workbooks.Open(<"file path">)
Dim oWS1210 As Worksheet: Set oWS1210 = oWB1210.Worksheets("Table1")
```

```
Dim Variable As Integer
Dim Variable1 As Integer
Dim Variable2 As Integer
Dim Variable3 As Integer
Dim Variable4 As Integer
Dim Variable5 As Integer
Dim Variable6 As Integer
Dim Variable7 As Integer
Dim Variable8 As Integer


Dim Cell As Range


'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
Application.EnableEvents = False  
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  

For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A22")
Variable1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(oWS9020.Range("A:A"), Cell.Value, oWS9020.Range("D:D"), "x", oWS9020.Range("F:F"), "y") _
+ Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(oWS8052.Range("A:A"), Cell.Value, oWS8052.Range("D:D"), "x", oWS8052.Range("F:F"), "y") _
+ <several more in a similar fashion, just another name>
Next Cell

oWB9020.Close False
oWB8052.Close False
<several more with different names>

Dim oWBNorth As Workbook: Set oWBNorth = Application.Workbooks.Open(<"file path">)
Dim oWSNorth As Worksheet: Set oWSNorth = oWBNorth.Worksheets("Table1")

<several more in a similar fashion, just another name and another path>

 For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A22")
Variable2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(oWSNorth.Range("A:A"), Cell.Value, oWSNorth.Range("D:D"), "x", oWSNorth.Range("F:F"), "y") _
+ Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(oWSSouth.Range("A:A"), Cell.Value, oWSSouth.Range("D:D"), "x", oWSSouth.Range("F:F"), "y") _
+ <several more in a similar fashion, just another name>
Next Cell
```

You get the idea I do this until i'm at Variable8

and then I do

```
For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A22")
Variable = Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3 + Variable4 + Variable5 + Variable6 + Variable7 + Variable8
Cell.Offset(0, 15).Value = Variable
Next Cell

ResetSettings:  
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings  
Application.EnableEvents = True  
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  

 End Sub
```

However what this shows me is 2 in every cell instead of 13 or something.

Any help would be appreciated, even if you just see something in my code that is needlessly complicated and could be done way easier.

No idea what im doing :D

Comment: If you had to explain to a co-worker in writing (not code) exactly what you're doing, how would you do that?  That's what you need to add to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of your code:

```
For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A22")
Variable = Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3 + Variable4 + Variable5 + Variable6 + Variable7 + Variable8
Cell.Offset(0, 15).Value = Variable
Next Cell
```

with this code:

```
For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A22")
    Debug.Print "Variable1 is ---> " & variable1
    Debug.Print "Variable2 is ---> " & variable2
    Debug.Print "Variable3 is ---> " & variable3
    Debug.Print "Variable4 is ---> " & variable4
    Debug.Print "Variable5 is ---> " & variable5
    Debug.Print "Variable6 is ---> " & variable6
    Debug.Print "Variable7 is ---> " & variable7
    Debug.Print "Variable8 is ---> " & variable8

    Variable = variable1 + variable2 + variable3 + variable4 + variable5 + variable6 + variable7 + variable8
    Cell.Offset(0, 15).Value = Variable

    Stop ' and read the values in the immediate window (CTRL+G)

Next Cell
```

Once it stops on the `Stop` line press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and see what is written on the *Immediate Window*. It will show you all the values you need.

Comment: FYI OP left you a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736010/vba-shows-the-wrong-value#comment86486502_49736010)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking the time. As i said im a super newb regarding vba. I'm a little confused with your answer. Can you explain in a little more detail what this does and how i need to utilize it? I added a cell.offset(x,y).value = Variablename to every instance and it shows the right values. i also added a debug.print variable name after every variable and it shows 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. Am pretty confused on why. Will also try your solution once i'm back at work tomorrow. Basically an explain like i'm five years old would be great? Thanks again.  Edit: also thank you @MathieuGuindon.

Comment: @SchlegelsBagels - I have edited the question. Take a look again. Concerning the arrays,  I do not see that you are using any. However, you can always try to google `"Arrays in VBA examples"` and take a look at the first 20 answers. Some of them are quite good.

Comment: I couldn't wait and went back. I tried what you asked me to do and it still displays 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. This is correct for A3 but it is not correct for any of the other dates (cell.value) in A4 to A22. The excel shows the dates in A3:A22 and i want it to look through the excels and tell me of all the cases that meet the countifs requirements at the specific dates and write the sum of them in cell.offset(0,15). I hope this is kind of understandable.

Comment: @SchlegelsBagels - I guess you mean it displays `2` instead of `13`. It is ok, it should be ok. The question is **What is displayed on the immediate window?**

Comment: @Vityata Variable1 is 2 Variable2 is 0 Variable3 is 0 Variable4 is 0 Variable5 is 0 Variable6 is 0 Variable7 is 0 Variable8 is 0 . This is correct for A3, but not for A4:A22. Thank you so much again.

Comment: @SchlegelsBagels - I guess there are other things displayed as well. However, how much should `Variable 1` be? Why is it 0? Using `Debug.Print` you could do fancy things like `Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(oWS9020.Range("A:A"), Cell.Value, oWS9020.Range("D:D"), "x", oWS9020.Range("F:F"), "y")` and see how much the value is and how much is it expected to be.

Comment: @Vityata In my opinion Variable1 should hold 1 value for each cell, right? So it should be 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = 2 for A3, but it should be 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 = 4 for A5 for example.

Comment: @SchlegelsBagels = `Variable1` holds only 1 value. As far as you are looping here - `For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A22")` it holds the value for `A22`. If you want the value for `A3`, change your loop to this - `For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A3")` and then read the first 20 articles for arrays in google.

Comment: If i add Cell.Offset(0,15).value = variablex where x is the variable number with differing columns into every loop. it displays 20 different values for each date in A3:A22. What i want is to display only the sum of all of these in cell.offset(0,15).